# Use [midway], [near end] etc. for weights in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

Is it possible to move weights of vertices using the commands `[midway]`, `[near end]`, `[near start]` etc? Just stating `{above}` and `{below}` doesn't always help, since the weights sometimes overlap:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4,auto,swap]
\foreach \pos /\name in {{(0,0)/4},{(1,0)/5},{(2,0)/6},{(0,1)/1},{(1,1)/2},{(2,1)/3}} \node[vertex](\name) at \pos{$\name$};
\foreach \source /\dest /\weight /\pos in {1/6/12/{above left},3/4/10/{above right},4/5/6/{below},5/6/9/{below},1/5/7/{above left},3/5/6/{right}} \path[edge] (\source) -- node[weight, \pos] {$\weight$} (\dest);
\foreach \source /\dest /\weight in {1/2/12,2/3/7,2/4/4,3/6/5,4/1/10,6/2/8} \path[arrow] (\source) -- node[weight] {$\weight$} (\dest);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This answer proposes a notion of relative position between [0 1] where 0 means `starting point` and 1 means `end point` of a line. Thus, `pos=0.1, 0.5, 0.9` would means `near start`, `midway` and `near end` respectively. By doing so words for location are turned into decimal numbers between `0` and `1`. These numbers can be defined by users in the `foreach` loop.

Note: The dotted color lines are for demonstration to see the weight between two nodes and can be removed easily from the `[options]`.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4,auto,swap]
\foreach \pos/\name in {{(0,0)/4},{(1,0)/5},{(2,0)/6},{(0,1)/1},{(1,1)/2},{(2,1)/3}}
{\node[draw,circle,black] (\name) at \pos{$\name$};}
\foreach \source /\dest /\weight /\pos in {1/6/12/0.1,3/4/10/0.25,4/5/6/0.40,5/6/9/0.65,1/5/7/0.80,3/5/6/0.95} 
{\path[draw,dotted,cyan] (\source) -- node[pos=\pos, above] {$\weight$} (\dest);}
\foreach \source /\dest /\weight/\pos in {1/2/12/0.1,2/3/7/0.25,2/4/4/0.40,3/6/5/0.65,4/1/10/0.8,6/2/8/0.95} 
{\path[draw,dotted, red] (\source) -- node[pos=\pos, below] {$\weight$} (\dest);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi! I corrected a small typo in the code. Hope you don't mind ;)

Comment: @tohecz, Hi, please do. thank you for your sharp eyes.

Comment: Thanks! That really helped me. Just wondering, If it possible to use both a place (above, below, etc) and a numeric value as \pos? Sometimes, telling all the nodes to be placed in one direction doesn't work out. I know it's possible to manually adjust those cases with a new "\foreach \source...", but what is it possible to avoid that?

Comment: @Nicholas -- Yes, you could use [pos=xx, above or below or right or left, above right, etc etc] simultaneously. So for each pos=xx, one has many choices to place the node text. In my view, pos=xx is very flexible. Thanks.