# Parallelogram with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to improve the following?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[xslant=1,xscale=3,scale=2]
    \draw (0,0) rectangle
          (1,1) coordinate(C) node[above]{C} -- (0,0) coordinate(A) node[below]{A}
          (1,0) coordinate(D) node[below]{y} -- (0,1) coordinate(B) node[above]{x};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I want to place `x+y` and `x-y` below the lines like in this picture:

[image]

Comment: You already got it.

Comment: I don't know how to write x-y and x+y under the lines @hpekristiansen

Comment: Add to preamble `\usetikzlibrary{calc}` and try, `\path ($(A)!0.5!(C)$)--(B)node[midway,below,left=1mm]{$x-y$}; 
    \path ($(A)!0.5!(C)$)--(C)node[midway,below]{$x+y$};        `

Comment: You need to search google and this site, before asking: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96846/how-to-place-label-in-middle-of-line-above-and-below-with-tikz . Is there something special/specific about your need, that is not solved there?

Comment: This could also help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/149138/8650

Comment: it works @hpekristiansen thank you

Comment: i want to draw a rectangle A(0.0), B(1,0), C(1,2), D(0,2) but it looks like a parallelogram not a rectangle how to do @hpekristiansen

Comment: @PolineSandra, you have to change the coordinates in parentheses. Also, remove the options `xslant=1,xscale=3` since they are changing bases vectors.

Comment: @PolineSandra, see mine above.

Comment: i understand @Sigur but now I want dots from C to D and from D to B how to do?

Comment: @Sigur:\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3] \draw (0,0) rectangle (2,1) coordinate(C) node[above]{} -- (0,0) coordinate(A) node[below]{} (0,1) coordinate(D) node[above]{} -- (2,0) coordinate(B) node[below]{y}; \path ($(B)!0.5!(D)$)--(D)node[midway,below,right=0.5mm]{$x-y$}; \path ($(A)!0.5!(C)$)--(C)node[midway,below]{$x+y$}; \path ($(A)!0.5!(D)$)--(A)node[midway,left=0.5mm]{$x$}; \end{tikzpicture}

Answer (score 3):

With tkz-euclide v2.42b (beta) actually only [here](http://altermundus.fr/files/euclide/geom_2.42b.zip)

```
%!TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
    %initialisation
    \tkzInit[xmin=0,xmax=4,ymin=0,ymax=2] 
    \tkzClip[space=.5] 
    %definitions
    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A} 
    \tkzDefPoint(3,0){B} 
    \tkzDefPoint(4,2){C} 
    \tkzDefPointWith[colinear= at C](B,A) \tkzGetPoint{D}
    %drawing
    \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C,D)
    \tkzDrawSegments[blue,dashed](A,C B,D)
    %label
    \tkzLabelPoints(A,B)
    \tkzLabelPoints[above right](C,D)
    \tkzLabelSegment[above,pos=.7,sloped](A,C){$x+y$}
    \tkzLabelSegment[above,pos=.7,sloped](B,D){$x-y$}
\end{tikzpicture}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Any reason why `tkz-euclide` is a package of his own and not a `tikz`-library?

Answer (score 2):

See if the following is what you looking for:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=7mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[xslant=1,xscale=3,yscale=2,
                      every node/.append style={inner xsep=0pt}
                      ]
    \draw (0,0) rectangle   (1,1);
    \draw (0,1) node[above] {$u$}
                to ["$u+y$",pos=0.3,swap] (1,0) node[below]{$y$}
          (0,0) to ["$u-y$",pos=0.7] (1,1);
\end{document}
```

[image]

or

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=7mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (n) [draw, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=2cm, xslant=1] {};
    \draw (n.south west) to ["$u+y$",pos=0.7,sloped] (n.north east)
          (n.north west) node[above] {$u$} 
                         to ["$u-y$",pos=0.3,sloped] (n.south east) node[below] {$y$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could just define a `pic` that draws a parallelogram. A parallelogram is defined by the lengths of two adjacent sides and the angle between them. These are store in the keys `x`, `y` and `angle`, respectively, in the `parallelogram` directory. With `name prefix` you can make the coordinate names unique if you draw several of them. To draw a parallelogram you only need to say

```
\draw (<x>,<y>) pic[name prefix=para1-]{parallelogram={x=<lenght 1>,y=<lenght 2>,angle=<angle>}};
```

Here is an example (if we drop `(<x>,<y>)` it is the default coordinate `(0,0)`).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[pics/parallelogram/.style={code={
   \tikzset{parallelogram/.cd,#1}
   \draw[pic actions] (0,0) coordinate (A) 
    -- ++ (0:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/parallelogram/x}) coordinate (B) 
    -- ++ (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/parallelogram/angle}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/parallelogram/y}) coordinate (C) 
    -- ++ (180:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/parallelogram/x}) coordinate (D) 
    -- cycle;       
   }},parallelogram/.cd,x/.initial=1,y/.initial=1,angle/.initial=45]
    \draw pic[name prefix=para1-]{parallelogram={x=4,y=2.5,angle=45}};
    \draw (para1-A) -- (para1-C) node[pos=0.33,sloped,above]{$u+y$};
    \draw (para1-D) node[above left]{$u$} -- (para1-B) node[below right] {$y$}
    node[pos=0.33,sloped,above]{$u-y$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer: I'm drawing now a rectangle but I want dots from C to D and from D to B how to do?

Comment: \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
    \draw (0,0) rectangle
          (2,1) coordinate(C) node[above]{} -- (0,0) coordinate(A) node[below]{}
          (0,1) coordinate(D) node[above]{} -- (2,0) coordinate(B) node[below]{y};
 \path ($(B)!0.5!(D)$)--(D)node[midway,below,right=0.5mm]{$x-y$};
  \path ($(A)!0.5!(C)$)--(C)node[midway,below]{$x+y$};   
  \path  ($(A)!0.5!(D)$)--(A)node[midway,left=0.5mm]{$x$};
  \end{tikzpicture}

Comment: @PolineSandra In the above code, replace the last two `\draw` commands by `\draw[dotted] (para1-A) -- (para1-C) node[pos=0.33,sloped,above]{$u+y$};
 \draw[dotted] (para1-D) node[above left]{$u$} -- (para1-B) node[below right] {$y$}
 node[pos=0.33,sloped,above]{$u-y$};`.

Comment: I don't understand who the two last draw?

Comment: I'm not with the parallelogram, I'm doing I rectangle now

Comment: @PolineSandra Sorry to hear that. Well, maybe this solution is useful for others.